# Create object by defining object name from string array in java

Tags: java

Normally, we create objects as :

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = "b";
String s3 = "c";
String s4 = "d";
...
```

I tried to create these with two string arrays:

```
String[] names = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4" };
String[] vals  = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

int len = names.length;

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
   String names[i] = vals[i];
}
```

But it does not work. What can I do?

Comment: Whats wrong with 'normal' way? What you expect to achive?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?? How to store data in key value pairs?

Comment: @talex Of course, you are right, but I can declare a method if I have to set a large objects.

Comment: This is an example, I have 40~50 strings must be set. So that, I tried to set by this way.

Comment: @Tarık İNCE Ok whats wrong with having 40-50 variables? You can create class with fields for each of them and use it to pass as parameter to method.

Comment: @talex I thought that, you said me to do this by normal way.

Comment: java doesn't allow to add members dinamically. If that is what you want than there is no way. You have to declare them statically or use a Map as workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your value and its content are different things.
In your example, you made a mistake:

```
String[] names = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4" };
String[] vals  = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

int len = names.length;

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
//name[i] already exists so you can remove String
   names[i] = vals[i];
}
```

And there are no s1, s2, etc Strings in your example, there is only names[] which is an array of String.
What are you trying to do?

It seems to me you are trying to have a key / value kind od data. So what you would need would be a Map.

For example:

```
Map<String, String> namesAndValues = new HashMap<String,String>();
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfNamesYouNeedToPut; i++){
// supposing vals's size is at least numberOfNamesYouNeedToPut
    namesAndValues.put("s" + i+1, vals[i]);
}
```

Comment: But I will use them after, for ex: setName(s2);

Comment: I edited for adding Map use case, does it look like it does the trick?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
   names[i] = vals[i];
}
```

It will just replace the values of String array names with the values of String array vals.

Moreover it `String names[i] = vals[i];` is not a valid array declaration and initialization.

Edit :

```
String newArray[] = new String[len];
System.arraycopy(vals,0,newArray,0,len);
```

this will copy the values to a new array.

Comment: Thanks, I ask that how can we declare an Object (String in here) with a dynamic name.

Comment: How you expect to use it.  You can look at Map interface (HashMap for example) if you need to store dinamic name-value pair.

Comment: There is no dynamic naming of variables in java what you want to do actually?